# returning only one response from the database in Django rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to return all the results from the SQL using this approach I'm able to retrieve it but its the static one.

I have tried looping the `result_set` but its returning only the first response out of 5 responses  but I want to return all the 5 response
Here, What I have tried

expected response:

```
[{"Value8":"Avail-On queue","Value1":"Avail-On queue"},{"Value8":"Coaching","Value1":"Coaching"},{"Value8":"Huddle","Value1":"Huddle"},{"Value8":"Outage","Value1":"Outage"},{"Value8":"Training","Value1":"Training"}]
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def GetClaimsActivity(request, UserId):
    if request.method == 'GET':
  
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaimsPlusActivity] @UserId=%s', (UserId,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()

        data = []
        # for row in result_set:
               #data.append({
                    #'Value8':row[0],
                    #'Value1':row[0],
            #})
            #return Reponse(data)


        data = []
              
        data.append({
                    'Value8':result_set[0][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[0][0],
            })
        data.append({
                   'Value8':result_set[1][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[1][0],
                })
        data.append({
                   'Value8':result_set[2][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[2][0],
                })
        
        data.append({
                   'Value8':result_set[3][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[3][0],
                })

        data.append({
                   'Value8':result_set[4][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[4][0],
                })
        
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: `for idx, row in enumerate(result_set): data.append({'Value8': value[idx][0],'Value1': value[idx][0] })`

Comment: Maybe `result_set[idx][0]` instead `value[idx][0]`?

Comment: @vovakirdan it was a typo, for idx, value ... . thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

````
@api_view(['GET'])
def GetClaimsActivity(request, UserId):
    if request.method == 'GET':
  
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaimsPlusActivity] @UserId=%s', (UserId,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()

        data = []
        for i in range(len(result_set)):
               data.append({
                    'Value8':result_set[i][0],
                    'Value1':result_set[i][0],
            })
        return Reponse(data)```
````